# Compactness of a composition operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Suppose $S:X\to Y$ is a continuous operator and $T:Y\to X$ is a compact operator, where $S,T$ need not be linear and hence $S$ need not be bounded. Then is the composition operator $TS:X\to X$ compact?
If in addition, we assume $T:Y\to X$ linear, bounded and compact, then is the operator $TS:X\to X$ compact?
Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the definition of a compact operator if you don't suppose that it is linear ?

Comment: I guess it's just a function such that the image of any bounded set is relatively compact.

Comment: Yes Sir, your definition is correct.

Comment: Is it true in the second case? Please reply...

Comment: The second case is very easy from the definitions - the fact that $S$ is bounded and $T$ is compact are all you need.

Comment: I am very sorry for the mistake in typing the second part of the question. Corrected question is updated and I am writing here again: If we assume $S:X→Y$ is a continuous operator  $T:Y→X$ linear, bounded and compact, then is the operator $TS:X→X$ compact?

Comment: If you can kindly reply, it will very helpful for me. Thanks you very much.